# Вызов Java Script без клика

Tags: javascript

Есть код всплывающей подсказки notification, показ через onclick

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.Notification.notify('custom','bottom right','название', 'Текст')">Тык</a>
```

Как сделать вывод при загрузке страницы. Пробовал вот так

```
<script type="text/javascript">$.Notification.notify('custom','bottom right','название', 'Текст');</script>
```

Не работает

Comment: очевидно вызывать надо после того как у тебя есть `$` и `$.Notification`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  $.Notification.notify('custom','bottom right','название', 'Текст');
});
```

и не раньше, чем подключаешь jQuery.